# don´t show glossaries in table of content

Tags: glossaries-extra

I want that glossaries disappears in the table of content

My code is

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nopostdot=false,
 stylemods=longragged,
 style=longragged3col,
 nogroupskip
]{glossaries-extra}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
\setlength{\glspagelistwidth}{0.12\textwidth}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{||.||}{name =  {$||.||$},
  description={Norm}}
  
\newcommand*{\glsxtrpostdescforeignenddot}{\space
 (Translation: \glsentryuseri{\glscurrententrylabel})}
\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\gls{||.||}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`glossaries-extra` has the package option `toc=true` by default, which adds the glossaries to the table of contents. As the [package documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/glossaries-extra) says:

> Use `toc=false` to switch this back off.

So add `toc=false` to your `\usepackage[...]{glossaries-extra}`.

Comment: thank you very much